# Order a set, maintaining multiple defined groupings

Tags: python, set

Since its hard for me to describe what I want in general, I try it with an example:

Given a set {x,y,z,d} and subsets {x,z}, {d,y} and {x,y}, I would like to order the first set {x,y,z,d} so that the small sets dont get torn apart (the permutation in each set is not important, so {x,y} or {y,x} is the same}.

The length of the example sets can be larger than what is given here. The small sets are always real subsets of the largest set.

I think it would be nice to have a way to say ok this part of the set has to stay in this configuration (x has to be next to y), but this part is arbitrary. Any recommendation how to do it?
I tried to do it with a tree, but I am completely failing with this problem:(

Comment: You cannot order a set, a set is unordered by definition. You could order a list, if that's what you're asking? If you do want to order a list, to meet the condition you described regarding those sets, it's an interesting problem, not trivial - have you tried anything yourself, or come up with some (partial) strategy? Am I right in concluding that `[d,y,x,z]` would be a solution here, as well as `[z,x,y,d]`?

Comment: are the subsets always size 2?

Comment: What you appear to be asking about is "permutations with restrictions". It's a large topic! Put the phrase I quoted into a search engine to find a world of info.

Comment: @Grismar You are right, I should talk about lists in this case. And yes, your solutions are correct. What I tried is: To consider every permutation of the first set and check if the subsets are conserved. But this brute force is not elegant, so I tried it with putting the lists in a tree, but by merging two lists into one, I lose information. So as I said, I am failing

Comment: @enke no, they can be larger

Comment: @TimPeters Thank you, I have never heard of it, this seems to be helpful

Comment: You're only interested in *a* solution, correct? Not all solutions? And there are no additional restrictions on the solution, i.e. no one solution is better than another?

Comment: @Grismar Yes, one solution is enough

Comment: Can the set or subset repeat values? (in other words: are they actually sets, where every element is unique, or are they in fact all unordered lists, with possible repeating values?) For example, could the problem consist of `[x, y, y, z]` and `[y, y], [x, z]`

Comment: No, there are no repetitions in the set/subset. I am still going through your answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a brute force solution lacks elegance, but it will certainly try many options that aren't worth considering:

```
from itertools import permutations


def find_ordering(main, subsets):
    for p in permutations(main):
        if all(any(set(p[i:i+len(s)]) == s 
                   for i in range(len(main) - len(s) + 1)) 
               for s in subsets):
            return p


print(find_ordering({1, 2, 3, 4}, [{1, 3}, {4, 2}, {1, 2}]))
```

Result:

```
(3, 1, 2, 4)
```

Edit: OK, that was a tough nut to crack, but here's a smarter solution:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import permutations


def shove(xs: set, yss: list[set]) -> list[set]:
    # move n up to the first part of yss that's not or only partially contained in xs
    # this works because there's no duplicates members among any members of yss
    n = 0
    while n < len(yss) and yss[n] <= xs:
        xs = xs - yss[n]
        n += 1
    # if xs could be shoved into yss entirely
    if not xs:
        return yss
    # if xs covers yss entirely, and some is left over
    elif n >= len(yss):
        return [xs] + yss
    else:
        # h, i, t = xs - yss[n], xs & yss[n], yss[n] - xs
        h, t = xs - (i := yss[n] & xs), yss[n] - i
        # avoid returning empty sets as part of the solution
        return ([h] if h else []) + yss[:n] + ([i] if i else []) + ([t] if t else []) + yss[n+1:]


def find_ordering(main: set, subsets: list[set]) -> list | None:
    # ensure there are no elements in subsets that are not in main
    if not set(reduce(set.union, subsets, set())) <= main:
        return None
    for p in permutations(subsets):
        solution = []
        solution_set = set()
        # try to shove subsets into each other, in order p
        for subset in p:
            solution = shove(subset, solution)
            # if new solution[0] contains elements in the prev solution, there's now duplicates
            if solution[0] & solution_set:
                break
            solution_set = solution_set.union(solution[0])
        else:
            # if all subsets could be shoved together, it's a solution, stop looking and return
            return [x for xs in solution for x in xs]


print(find_ordering({1, 2, 3, 4}, [{1, 3}, {4, 2}, {1, 2}]))
print(find_ordering({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, [{1, 3}, {4, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, 7}]))
print(find_ordering({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, [{1, 6}, {2, 1, 4}, {7, 3}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}]))
```

Result:

```
[4, 2, 1, 3]
[7, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]
```

The approach hinges on the idea of shoving subsets into each other. If you shove `{1, 2}` into `[{2, 3, 4}]`, the outcome is `[{1}, {2}, {3, 4}]` - i.e. a fixed ordering of sets that still contains the groupings in the original sets. `3` and `4` can still change places and the ordering will hold, but none of the sets can change place or the ordering is broken. The `shove()` function performs this operation. When shoving, it never changes the order of the sets in the list, but it ignores the order of elements in the sets for matching (as expected).

The `find_ordering()` function uses shove to try and shove subsets into each other in every possible order (using permutations of the subsets).

If the first set in an expanded solution (after a shove) contains any elements that were already in the solution, it means there's now a duplicate in the solution and it won't work, so it moves on to the next permutation.

Before starting `find_ordering()`, it checks if the subsets actually solely consist of elements of `main`, because otherwise it would try them all while a solution is impossible. In that case, or if no permutation works, the function returns `None`.

That was a fun question, thanks. If you see any issue with this solution, do let me know.

Edit: you correctly identified a problem with the solution - turns out there were 3 problems, but I think this is better. Don't drink and code, kids.

Comment: I dont understand how the last solution ```{1} {2, 3} {4} {2, 5}```should form a valid solution, so why to care about it?

Comment: I agree, it has a repetition, it's why I asked about repetition, but since you say there's no repetition within any of the subsets, nor in the main, it would not be valid - I'm thinking about a smarter solution that implements this type of matching... It's not easy though

Comment: Glad to hear thats also not easy for you:) I am looking for a smarter solution since I have the hope that if a subset cannot be added, maybe a part of the subset still can. For example given the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7} and the subsets [{0, 4}, {0, 7}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 7}], the last subset cant be added. Removing the 2 from this last subset, it is possible again. I thought, with a smart solution - I may see which subset makes problems and what to change

Comment: I think I solved it - that was an interesting nut to crack. It doesn't exactly allow what you suggested in your last comment, but allows you to get close - although if that's your aim, you may end up having to compute far more options anyway.

Comment: That looks promising, thank you! The last print statement shows an error. The 6 occurs twice, and the 5 is missing